# How many ways are there to distribute $n$ different gifts to $m$ people？

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I met a math question. Let's say there are $m$ people and $n$ gifts. A person may receive all $n$ gifts or $a$ ($0 \leq a \leq n$) gifts or nothing ($0$ gifts). But all the gifts need to be given away. In addition, all the gifts are different. So, my question is how many possible ways are there to send the gifts?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: **Hint:** How many possible recipients are there for each gift?

Answer (score -1):

Since each gift can be assigned to $m$ different people, then you have $m$ possibilities for each of the $n$ gifts, this means that the total combinations are given by multiplying $m$ by itself $n$ times, so $m^n$.

Intuitively, you can think about this as counting in how many ways you can map $n$ gifts to $m$ people, maybe trying to sketch a drawing with arrows from gifts to people helps, try it for small numbers of $m$ and $n$.

Hope this helps!